# How can I publish an update to Android application with a different developer account?

Tags: android

We are migrating to a new Android developer account and I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions about the best way to transition apps to the new account.

From what I can find, the only suggestions I've seen were to publish an update to the old app notifying the user of the new updated app. This requires us to publish the apps under a new package name which we would like to avoid if possible.

Has anyone else been in this situation and if so, what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you contacted Google? Since you'll be using the same key to sign the app (you will, right?), it should be possible for them to transfer the app to your new account. I haven't tried that myself, but that should be your first course of action.

Of course, if you use a different key, there's no way for you to do it other than by deprecating the old app and pointing users to the new one.